# Real Time Messaging with database updation in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, real-time-updates

In my website there is messaging system, in which i want to show realtime popup when a message is received by a user.

There is table in database in which messages are stored when a user receives a message a new row will be inserted with that user id in database.

Currently i have done with ajax timer.

How can i do it with comet ajax or is there any other technology or any example programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/) which is designed for those kind of scenarios. Contrary to continuous polling with AJAX it uses PUSH technique where the server can send data to the client. In modern browsers that support HTML5, WebSockets are used to achieve that.

Comment: can i use PokeIn or SignalR? which is better?

Comment: Yes, you can use that as well.